# Input при заданном padding вылезает за рамки div

Tags: html, css

Почему то при назначении padding текстовые поля выходят за границы div, что я не так делаю?

код:

```css
    input[type="text"]{
      padding: 8px 12px;
      display: block;
      margin: 10px 0;
      border: 1px solid #ccc;
      border-radius: 4px;
      width: 100%;
    }
    
    .auth_form{
      width: 210px;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="auth_form ">
        <h3>Авторизация</h3>
        <input type="text" class="" placeholder="Электронная почта"/>
        <input type="text" class="" placeholder="Пароль"/>
        <button type="button" >Вход</button>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавьте к полям свойство `box-sizing: border-box;`. Из за данного свойства `width` будет включать в себя значения `border` и `padding`. Так же рекомендую почитать про `box-model`.

```css
input[type="text"]{
      padding: 8px 12px;
      display: block;
      margin: 10px 0;
      border: 1px solid #ccc;
      border-radius: 4px;
      width: 100%;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    
    .auth_form{
      width: 210px;
    }
```

```html
<div class="auth_form ">
        <h3>Авторизация</h3>
        <input type="text" class="" placeholder="Электронная почта"/>
        <input type="text" class="" placeholder="Пароль"/>
        <button type="button" >Вход</button>
      </div>
```

Comment: Благодарю, не знал такое свойство=)

Comment: @Чайник, Если вы используете фиксированую ширину, то лучше задать данное свойство ко всем елементам через селектор `*`